# sql to find today,tomorrow and yesterday birthday

Tags: mysql

In sql i m trying to connect to database and find today,tomorrow and yesterdays's birthday and the sql code looks something like this

```
SELECT 
Emp_Name,
DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%d-%b') AS dob
FROM mldob.tbl_mldob WHERE  
    DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%m-%d') IN (
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d'),
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d'),
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d')
  )
  order by(emp_dob);
```

but EMP_DOB column is showing empty and the same MySql query is working fine in mysql workbench. so can anyone please suggest me where i m going wrong and possible solution to achieve the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any error output?

Comment: here i m trying to display employee name and corresponding date of birth but i can see only employee name whose birthday is today tomorrow and yesterday but not birthday date. the complete EMP_DOB column is empty

Comment: Are you certain that you get a different result directly on Workbench?

Answer (score 1):

use Emp_DOB instead 'dob'

```
 SELECT 
    Emp_Name,
    DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%d-%b') AS  Emp_DOB
    FROM mldob.tbl_mldob WHERE  
        DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%m-%d') IN (
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d')
      )
      order by(emp_dob);
```

Comment: in mysql workbench i get the desired result both EMP_NAME and EMP_DOB  columns displays perfectly fine which displays employees name and birthday date whose birthday is today,tomorrow and yesterday but in jsp the logic is working fine but EMP_DOB column is empty mean to say employees name whose birthday is today,tomorrow and yesterday is displayed but EMP_DOB column is empty for corresponding employee name.

Comment: "${row.Emp_DOB}" this line will read the column named as Emp_DOB but there there is not column returned in that name.so you are getting null value. Please change the dob to 'Emp_DOB' .

Comment: PLease check in mysql Work bench there is no column in the name of Emp_DBO.But you are trying to read Emp_DBO in jsb page

Comment: hi thanks the above solution is working fine. now i am able to display EMP_DOB column values.